# How to sort a WP_Query array by post_name after an array_merge();

Tags: wp-query, array, sort

I have an WP_Query array made up from two WP_Query() objects merged together as follows:

```
$query1 = new WP_Query($args1);
$query2 = new WP_Query($args2);     

$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->posts = array_merge( $query1->posts, $query2->posts );
```

Each of the original queries are ordered by name - 'orderby' => 'post_name' - but array merge doesn't obviously respect that.

Does anyone know a way to sort $wp_query arrays after they have been populated? Or do I have to fathom and write a custom php sorting function of my own?

thanks

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but php's array_multisort function allows you to sort by key value. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: Agreed. More of a pure PHP question I think.

Comment: Thanks for the comments - had arrived at the same conclusion. array_multisort it is then - fun fun